# Selecting data based on values in multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame and I need to select data that has [1,2,3,4,5] in the [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5] fields respectively.

```
ID  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
1   1   2   3   4   5
2   2   3   4   5   6
3   1   2   3   4   5
4   5   4   2   3   4


df = DataFrame(numpy.array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                            [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                            [4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=int64), 
               columns = ['ID','f1','f2','f3','f4','f5'])
```

An obvious way is to do the following:

```
df[(df['f1'] == 1) & (df['f2'] == 2) & (df['f3'] == 3) & (df['f4'] == 4) & (df['f5'] == 5)]
```

Is there any concise way to do this? I need to do it multiple times and the field names may be different for some other DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly simpler way could be:

```
>>> df[(df.loc[:, 'f1':'f5'] == np.arange(1, 6)).all(1)]
   ID  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
0   1   1   2   3   4   5
2   3   1   2   3   4   5
```

Here `df.loc[:, 'f1':'f5']` chooses the columns, and these are tested (row-wise) for equality with the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.